# AttributeError: 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite

i define my sprite by using

```
user = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
```

then later i try to do this:

```
user.image == pygame.image.load(userstationary).convert()
```

but i get the error in the title

any help is appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You get the error because a `Sprite` object doesn't have an `image` attribute...

Comment: Post a full traceback, and full source code to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to a misunderstanding of the purpose of the `Sprite` class in pygame. It is not intended to be used directly, but rather it should be a base class for you to use to define your own subclasses.

So, you might define a minimal class of your own like this:

```
class User(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You used == instead of =. For example, instead of `user.image == pygame.image.load(userstationary).convert()`, you need to put `user.image = pygame.image.load(userstationary).convert()`